# Android Service: Dependency injection?

Tags: android, testing, servicetestcase

I'm trying to unittest my Service through a [ServiceTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html), but try to do so without using Guice or RoboGuice (Because of [Avoid dependency injection frameworks](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection%20Avoid%20dependency%20injection%20frameworks)). I want to inject a dependency other than Application or Context, but can't get it working:

1. I cannot insert it through a custom constructor
2. [setupService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html#setupService%28%29) would seem like the right method based on the name, but has no arguments and no return value

I could make my utility class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and inject it through the Intent, but that seems forced. Any ideas?